# How do I redeem an iBooks free coupon?

Tags: ipad, data-transfer, books

I remember a message after installing the iBooks app on my iPad telling me that I would have one free book to download. I never used it but now I am interested and wonder if this coupon is still active.

How could I know without spending money accidentally?

Answer (score 1):

- Find the redeem code button in the iBook store.
- Enter Your Promo Code
- Push redeem button
- After you entered your promo code, you will (hopefully) get a message saying that your item is downloading.

Comment: what promo code?